# Contour plot labels every 100m

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour

I have bathymetry data of the Mediterranean sea that I am plotting using `contour`

```
%open netcdf file 
latu=ncread('/media/Elise/ELISEV32/LECOB/Netcdf1/grid.nc','latitude_u'); 
lonu=ncread('/media/Elise/ELISEV32/LECOB/Netcdf1/grid.nc','longitude_u');

depw=ncread('/media/Elise/ELISEV32/LECOB/Netcdf1/grid.nc','depth_w');
    [m,n]=size(depw(:,:,1));
    %Delete values with a depth deeper than 4000 to increase the accuracy of the map since the default value of no data is -999999
    for i=1:m
        for j =1:n
            if depw(i,j,1) <-4000
                depw(i,j,1);
                depw(i,j,1)= NaN;
            end
        end
    end

figure

[M,c]=contour(lonu(1:681,1:711),latu(1:681,1:711),depw(1:681,1:711,1),50,'ShowText','on');
```

This gives me the following map of the gulf of Lions in south france. 
[image]

As you can see, this is not readable. Is there a way to only plot the text every ten lines or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the `TextList` property of the `contour` object:

```
num_lines = 30;
line_skip = 5;

[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25);

figure(1); clf;
[M,c] = contour(X,Y,Z,num_lines,'ShowText','on');

c.TextList = c.TextList(1:line_skip:end);
```

[image]